# Cumulative aggregate of unique string values

Tags: python, pandas

Here is what I have:

```
import pandas as  pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['date'] = ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-01','2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-03']
df['value'] = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C']
df
           date value
0   2020-01-01      A
1   2020-01-01      A
2   2020-01-01      A
3   2020-01-02      A
4   2020-01-02      B
5   2020-01-03      A
6   2020-01-03      C
```

I want to aggregate unique values over time like this:

```
           date value
0   2020-01-01      1
3   2020-01-02      2
5   2020-01-03      3
```

I am ***NOT*** looking for this as an answer:

```
           date value
0   2020-01-01      1
3   2020-01-02      2
5   2020-01-03      2
```

I need the `2020-01-03` to be `3` because there are three unique values (A,B,C).

Comment: so if `2020-01-2` has `B` then that forward fills into `2020-01-03` ?

Comment: Yes. `2020-01-01` would  be 1 because there is one unique value (A). `2020-01-02` would  be 2 because  unique `B` value aggregates with the previous count. `2020-01-03` would be 3 because `C` is the new unique value.

Comment: Maybe I should've phrased it "rolling" aggregate.

Comment: It's more *cumulative* than *rolling*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can do `agg` `list` with `cumsum`

```
s=df.groupby('date').value.agg(list).cumsum().map(set).map(len)
date
2020-01-01    1
2020-01-02    2
2020-01-03    3
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: while this works, `cumsum` on lists is extremely costly and can blow up pretty fast. Still neat idea +1.

Answer (score 4):

Let's use pd.crosstab instead:

```
(pd.crosstab(df['date'], df['value']) !=0).cummax().sum(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
date
2020-01-01    1
2020-01-02    2
2020-01-03    3
dtype: int64
```

***Details:***

First, let's reshape the dataframe such that you have 'date' as rows and the values listed across as columns.  Then check for non-zero cells and use cummax in the column to keep track of every "value" seen in a column, then use sum across rows to calculate how many distinct values are seen at any point in time in the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

I think,`np.cumsum` the first unique values. `.groupby` the `date` which in this case I have set as the `index` and find either the maximum or last value.

```
import numpy as np
    (np.cumsum((~(df.set_index('date')).duplicated('value')))).groupby(level=0).max()

date
2020-01-01    1
2020-01-02    2
2020-01-03    3
```